# Image from public directory not loading Express NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I am writing an express app, i have a public directory and it has one image in it. In the app.js file I use the line "app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));" so express knows to use this folder.

The image loads on some pages and on other pages it doesn't, it loads on pages with URLs where its only one word after the base url, for example [www.amazonaws.com/blogs](http://www.amazonaws.com/blogs) or [www.amazonaws.com/login](http://www.amazonaws.com/login) but image doesn't load on pages with URLs such as [www.amazonaws.com/blogs/best](http://www.amazonaws.com/blogs/best) or [www.amazonaws.com/blogs/102](http://www.amazonaws.com/blogs/102).

I'm using ejs files and they are all in the same folder, so for example the 'blogs' ejs file which is used for [www.amazonaws.com/blogs](http://www.amazonaws.com/blogs) works fine, but for the 'best' ejs file for [www.amazonaws.com/blogs/best](http://www.amazonaws.com/blogs/best) everthying works fine except this image does not load. Not sure why this is? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would you kindly show some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL to your image in the web page needs to start with `/` so it is not a "path-relative" URL.   From your symptoms, it sounds like your image URL in the page is just a plain name such as:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

When you do it like that, then the browser will take the path of your web page and combine it with the filename and which URL the browser requests will differ based on whether the web page has a path or not.  If, instead, you do this:

```
<img src="/image.jpg">
```

Then, the browser will only use the domain of the web page, not the path and you will get a consistent URL no matter which web page path this link is in because this is an absolute path, not a relative path.

Comment: That was the issue, adding the forward slash fixed it, thanks a lot